# MYSQL has 2 tables. Same dates total. Compare and subtract dates

Tags: mysql, date, sum, subtraction

```
​tablo1                             tablo2
--------------------------         ------------------------------
fiyat1         tarih1              fiyat2            tarih2
----------     ------------        -----------        -----------
1200           03-2017             2100               03-2017
1050           03-2017             5200               03-2017   
3250           04-2017             3200               04-2017
2501           04-2017              
6100           05-2017
1100           05-2017
```

---

Collecting the same dates at price 1, collecting the same dates at price 2, 
subtract 2 totals, group by date.

I want to print something like this:

```
-----------------------
05-2017      7200
04-2017      2511
03-2017     -5050
```

The question is true, but the result is wrong. I tried this.

```
SELECT   tablo1.tarih1,
         tablo1.fiyat1,
         SUM(tablo1.fiyat1),
         tablo2.tarih2,
         tablo2.fiyat2,
         SUM(tablo1.fiyat1),
         (SUM(tablo1.fiyat1) - SUM(tablo2.fiyat2)) AS sonuc
FROM     tablo1 INNER JOIN
         tablo2 ON tablo1.tarih1 = tablo2.tarih2
GROUP BY tablo1.tarih1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the table structure being as it is, the query that can be written to get the desired result is:

```
SELECT t1.tarih1, (COALESCE(t1.fiyat1, 0) - COALESCE(t2.fiyat2, 0)) AS sonuc
FROM
    (SELECT tarih1, SUM(fiyat1) AS fiyat1
         FROM tablo1
     GROUP BY tarih1
    ) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT tarih2, SUM(fiyat2) AS fiyat2
         FROM tablo2
     GROUP BY tarih2
    ) AS t2
    ON t1.tarih1 = t2.tarih2
ORDER BY t1.tarih1 DESC;
```

However, I'd like to offer a couple of suggestions:

- It's generally a good idea to store the date in MySQL `date` format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. It'll be much easier for you to run yearly reports, if there ever was a need.
- As far as book-keeping is concerned, maybe you'll find the following Q&A to be of your interest: [What is a common way to save 'debit' and 'credit' information?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17197/124935)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have this column but I get such a warning.
Unknown column 'tablo1.tarih1' in 'field list'

Comment: Seems to run ok for me - see this [rextester link](http://rextester.com/NQI27632)

Comment: I made a mistake. Now it works perfectly. I will examine this subject "What is a common way to save 'debit' and 'credit' information?" Thank you so much.

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming! Glad that it works for you :)